# Iterating a JSON and having an infinite loop

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I am trying to iterate a JSON structure in a recursive way. I checked other forums / stackoverflow questions but I seem to have a strange problem.
So what comes from the REST service is :

```
{/Envelope=
    {/Envelope/Header = {},
     /Envelope/Body = 
         {/Envelope/Body/ns:GetAddressForPostCodeResponse=
             {/Envelope/Body/ns:GetAddressForPostCodeResponse/ns:maximumAddressMatches =  ? ,
              /Envelope/Body/ns:GetAddressForPostCodeResponse/ns:postalAddress = 
                 {/Envelope/Body/ns:GetAddressForPostCodeResponse/ns:postalAddress/ns:apartment =  ? ,
...
```

Basically I send back a Map from SpringMVC with a String key and having an other Map as value.

The (angular) code:

```
$scope.getHtml = function(node, isAdd) {
    if (isAdd) {
        var html = "<ul id='tree1'>";
    } else {
        var html = "<ul>";
    }

    //angular.forEach(node, function(value, key) {
    for (var key in node) {
        if (node.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            var value = node[key];
            console.log(key + "  :  " + value);
            console.log(node.hasOwnProperty(key));
            if (key != "$promise" && key != "$resolved") {
                html += "<li><input type='checkbox' id='" + key + "'><label>" + key + "</label>";
                html += $scope.getHtml(value, false);
            }
        }
    //});
    }

    html += "</ul>";
    delete node;
    return html;
};
```

As you can see there is a recursive call.

And what I can see in the console:

```
true                   serviceDiscovery.controller.js:39
"0  :  ?"              serviceDiscovery.controller.js:38
true                   serviceDiscovery.controller.js:39
"0  :  ?"              serviceDiscovery.controller.js:38
... (the same two rows some thousands times)
"0  :  ?"              serviceDiscovery.controller.js:38
true                   serviceDiscovery.controller.js:39
"Error: too much recursion
$scope.getHtml/<@http://localhost:8080/management-app-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/resources/js/serviceDiscovery.controller.js:37:21
r@http://localhost:8080/management-app-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/resources/js/angularjs/angular.min.js:7:288
```

So there is an infinite loop but how...? I tried the angular.forEach too.
Any idea?

------------- UPDATE -------------
Hmm, my mistake, sorry. I only need the recursive call if the value is a map (object) and not a String.

Comment: Your JSON structure looks really weird (all quotes missing, for one) and the console output doesn't match the input you are giving us... Besides you don't even test if `node` is a valid object in the first place.

Comment: Are you ever using [JSON.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse "Description of the native JSON parsing API.") to make sure you are processing valid JSON?